# Enable == False is not working for UI disabled button in tosca

Tags: user-interface, button, web-applications, disable, tosca

We are using angular 9 and typescript as Frontend and trying to scan a UI page. I was able to scan. but for the button the enable is always coming true even in UI the button is disabled.

[image]

I want to test a button is enabled or disabled

Comment: can you paste your code snippet instead of the image you are using

Comment: <button color="primary" class="mat-focus-indicator padding-right-12X rx-command-bar-button mat-flat-button mat-button-base mat-primary" ng-reflect-color="primary" ng-reflect-disabled="true" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-commands-count="4" disabled="true"><span class="mat-button-wrapper"><mat-icon role="img" class="mat-icon notranslate mat-icon-no-color ng-star-inserted" aria-hidden="true" ng-reflect-svg-icon="cancel_outline"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 32 32" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fit="" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false">

Comment: ng-reflect-disabled="true" value is changing for enable and disable